# Disable the "hover" scrolling effect of a scrolling menu and use a vertical scrollbar instead

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

How can I disable the default scrolling effect of a menu and just use a vertical scrollbar. I am able to use the scrollbar when I set overflowY to 'auto'. However, the mouse scroll wheel doesn't work as expected anymore, and the behavior in general is just wonky. I suspect it is because both scrolling is in effect and they are comflicting with each other.

I'm not sure if there is a config option that I am missing. The weird behavior can be seen here: [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/c04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working around this issue by simply embedding a panel with a fixed size as a menu item, and then adding all the components to the panel instead. This gives me a lot more flexibility to layout the items, and not have to worry about the inconsistent scrolling of an overflown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a height / maxHeight on the menu and setting overflowY:'scroll' ?

Comment: Yeah I've tried both of those, and they don't seem to change the behavior.

Comment: In this fiddle, i get the expected behaviour i think..
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/bv3
The only thing i could describe as wonky is when the lager window is also scrollable, and you scroll on the menu, the window will also scroll a bit.. is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry I was misleading you by linking to the 5.0 example page, but I am actually using ExtJS 4.2.1. So, 2 things: 1) there is a small typo at overflowY (Y is not capitalized) in the fiddle. But yes if you make that small correction and run it, it does work as inteneded, as in the scroll bar appears and scrolling works well. But when you change the target framework to 4.2.1, you will see what I mean. The scrolling using a scrollwheel in the menu area doesn't work, but if you scrollwheel over the scrollbar area it does work.

Comment: Well i don't know if this is a viable solution for you, and the code isn't the cleanest, but i got the mousewheel working in 4.2 by adding a scroll listener to the menu items, it might need some calibrating on the scroll size, and also the dom search could be better but it works as it is (on the fiddle). If you really must have the scrollwheel disabled,i guess you'd need to try and cancel the event. Personally, i think it's more user-friendly to have the scrolling working but it always depends on what you're trying to do. Hope it helped. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/bv3 (tested on chrome)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I ended up working around the problem by using a panel inside the menu instead. It actually gives me much more flexibility to layout the components without having to deal with the inconsistent scrolling issue.